# Difference in creating PXCMSenseManager with Intel RealSense

Tags: c#, intel, realsense

I found that i can create `PXCMSenseManager` in 2 different ways (as i think now)

First one :

- Create `session` and then from it get senseManager

  `var session = PXCMSession.CreateInstance();
  var sm = session.CreateSenseManager();`
- Second way - just create instance from PXCMSenseManager class

  `var pp = PXCMSenseManager.CreateInstance();`

I haven't found any documentation that can explain what way is correct. Hope there smbd can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of the [`PXCMSenseManager.CreateInstance();` method](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?createinstance_pxcsensemanager.html) states:

> This is a convenience function that skips session creation.

Too me, that says that either way is fine. If you need the `Session` before the `SenseManager` (for example to create some of the other modules), then create the session first.

Otherwise just go straight to the SenseManager. The SenseManager then creates a session for you and if you need the session later on, just use [`SenseManager::QuerySession()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?querysession_pxcsensemanager.html)